# Pull-style cross region replication for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to pull data published to an S3 bucket by a different organization (therefore a different AWS account) in a different region, for subsequent processing with Lambda. I do have access to read it but cannot ask them to set up replication to my buckets.

Amazon's [Cross-Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) looks like it's designed for pushing data from the source and I'm not even sure the source organization has versioning enabled.

Is there a way to *pull* data? My need is for one-way only; I need to process that data shortly (within 10 minutes or so) after it arrives in the source S3 bucket.

Comment: A cron-job that runs `aws s3 sync` every 10 minutes? Something like that is going to be the best way to pull from an S3 bucket I think, if you can't get new object events sent to you from that bucket.

Comment: Is there a way to run this as a lambda? I'm thinking of the cost of running an EC2 instance just to run the sync. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run `aws s3 sync` on a schedule, like every 10 minutes. If you want to run this in a AWS Lambda function, [it looks like](https://serverfault.com/questions/737942/run-aws-cli-commands-on-aws-lambda-function) NodeJS and Python Lambda environments have the AWS CLI tool pre-installed. I would suggest writing a short Python Lambda function that calls the AWS CLI took to run an `s3 sync` command, and schedule that Lambda function to run every 10 minutes.

Comment: I would use a CloudWatch Rule to trigger the lambda on a schedule

Comment: @DavidWebster yes that is how you schedule a Lambda function

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try the moment I can and then will accept the answer (with any details that might be useful to others who might visit the page).